# What word could you use for seeing a picture then seeing the real thing later?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been searching everywhere for a verb that means seeing a picture of something then seeing the real thing later.

Comment: I'd say "deja view".

Comment: Plane-spotting from photos was/is called 'Recognition'.  I thought Déjà vu was something you imagined or believed you had seen.

Comment: @Hugh - I didn't say "vu".

Comment: see something with one's own eyes ?

Comment: Why would you think there should be such a verb?  Perhaps you should broaden your question to accept a phrase or an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Recognize  (Wiktionary)

> identify (someone or something) from having encountered them before;
>   know again. Example "I recognized her when her wig fell off"

Identify  (Dictionary.com)

> 5.Biology. to determine to what group (a given specimen) belongs.

Encounter (Oxford OL)

> 2. Meet (someone) unexpectedly: what do we know about the people we encounter in our daily lives?

Answer (score 0):

> serendipity

It if was a pleasant surprise.